# How to get perf fully working with all features?

Tags: package-management

I've installed the following packages:
`linux-tools-common`, `linux-tools-generic` and `linux-cloud-tools-generic`

I now have `perf` but it's a bit broken.

1 -

```
sudo perf report --gtk
GTK browser requested but could not find libperf-gtk.so
```

I've opened a bug for the missing library: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1843114

2 -
When running `sudo perf report` and opening a function in the TUI I can select **Annotate [function-name]** but the GUI throws back an error and says

```
Cannot load tips.txt file, please install perf!
```

Which looks a lot like this Fedora issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1448402

I'd like a fully working `perf`. Whats the easiest way to go about getting that? Is there a PPA I should look at? Or building/installing from source?

Answer (score 18):

Regarding:

```
Cannot load tips.txt file, please install perf!
```

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04. TL;DR the error message is benign.

The tips.txt file comes from: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master/tools/perf/Documentation/tips.txt

As described in the original commit the purpose of this file is to show a random usage tip on the help line.

So if you wanted to get rid of the message, copy the appropriate
`tips.txt` to `/usr/share/doc/perf-tip/tips.txt`.