# Generic way to get perf woking on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04

I have installed `inux-tools-generic` and `inux-tools-common` - the usual suggestions to get `perf` to work. But I'm still getting the error:

> WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.15.0-41
>
> You may need to install the following packages for this specific
> kernel:
> linux-tools-5.15.0-41-generic
> linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-41-generic

I don't want to install the specific package for the kernel and then have to manually install a new one as the kernel gets updated. Also, I cannot hard-code the kernel version into scripts for various machines, including cloud CI workers. Is there a generic way?

P. S. After installing `linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-41-generic` it finally works, but when using `perf report` I get the following text in the bottom - does this mean it's still not completely installed?

> Cannot load tips.txt file, please install perf!

Comment: This ever get solved? There is not way to get a valid perf installed through apt.

Comment: @JohnGlen: I didn't solve it, I gave up on running perf, will profile on Windows where software works properly. Please share your findings if you fix it!

Comment: I did post
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1476192/i-can-not-get-perf-on-freshly-installed-22-04-2-lts
I will probably try Ubuntu forums too.

Comment: Related to the tips.txt issue, the solution can be found at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1209777/235996).

Comment: That message can be safely ignored, it's just a small optional feature which I wouldn't bother about, advertising itself. perf works for me out of the box on 22.04.